# Opening link in a new tab on iPhone Safari does not change tab

Tags: iphone, safari, tabs, mobile-safari

I have a link with a `target= "__blank"` attribute on my mobile website.

When I use Safari on an Iphone, if the user clicks on the link, it effectively opens a new tab and everything is fine.

However, if I come back to my website with the link being still open, and I click on another link, the tab that has been opened with the previous link reloads with the new link. But I am not redirected to this tab, so I don't see anything happening on the screen, even though I just clicked on a link.

Do you have a solution to this problem please?

Comment: Is the `__` a typo? Shouldn't it be `_blank`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Tarun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani) says in comments, the problem should come from the double underscore. Replace it with `target=“_blank”` it should work. 
Here’s the MDN for the `<a>` tag : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a